# Text has turned to boxes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts, text

Without any cause that I can tell, all text has turned into boxes /rectangles everywhere in Ubuntu 16.04.

I am able to press ctrl-alt-F1 and go to shell,  I have run :

```
apt-get update
```

And

```
apt-get upgrade
```

But this has not changed anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `fc-cache -fr` (and reboot).

Comment: This happens for me too. I just log out and log in back to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried (re)setting the system language & region settings? They are in System Settings / Language Support. After setting them, click "Apply System Wide" (assuming all users on your computer share locale preferences). **Note**: changes take effect after reboot.

Answer (score 11):

This can be the result of some invalid permissions settings on Font files. You need to set correct permissions for fonts.

To fix the permissions of all fonts ending with `.ttf` or `.otf` extension use these two commands.

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.ttf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.otf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;
```

Then use this command to re-build font cache

```
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: +1, work like a charm !!!

Comment: The two chmod lines can be shortened to one: 
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.[ot]tf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;

Comment: This is the way.