# Ubuntu 16.04 Font has changed abnormaly

Tags: fonts, text

[image: screen shot with rectangles instead of letters]
Instead of text, it's showing all blocks.

Comment: please check this link out .https://askubuntu.com/questions/843533/text-has-turned-to-boxes-in-ubuntu-16-04 if this helps then tell us so we can flag it as duplicate and if not then edit you questions with terminal output

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?

Comment: does this helps?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  It worked for me.